# Fall back to Flask's default session manager when session database is down?

Tags: python, flask

I'm using SqlAlchemy for my session management database, and have created a custom `SessionInterface` as per the documentation.

My dev database went down today, and now I cannot access my site, as would be expected. Is there a way for me to fall back to Flask's default session manager in this event?

Here is my current implementation of `SessionInterface`

```
class SqlAlchemySessionInterface(SessionInterface):
    #...
    def open_session(self, app, request):
        sid = request.cookies.get(app.session_cookie_name)
        if sid:
            # error is raised here when database is down
            stored_session = DBSession.query.filter_by(sid=sid).first()
            # ...
```

I have a naive solution to the problem of a crashed database, that leverages a in memory dict as a backup:

```
# A backup memory storage for sessions
backup = {}
class SqlAlchemySessionInterface(SessionInterface):
    #...
    def open_session(self, app, request):
        sid = request.cookies.get(app.session_cookie_name)
        if sid:
            try:
                stored_session = DBSession.query.filter_by(sid=sid).first()
            except DatabaseError:
                stored_session = backup.get('sid')
                # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend a default `secure cookie` session interface implementation.

```
class ReliableSessionInterface(SecureCookieSessionInterface):
    def open_session(self, app, request):
        try:
            return self._open_db_session(app, request)
        except DatabaseError:
            return super().open_session(app, request)

    def save_session(app, session, response):
        try:
            self._save_session_to_db(app, session, response)
        except DatabaseError:
            super().save_session(app, session, response)
```

However, such requirement sounds a little bit strange.